# Can I move app purchases from one Apple ID to another?

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id

Can I move apps purchased with one Apple ID to another Apple ID? I am looking at purchasing a used iOS device and I want to be able to keep all the apps that are on the device (with permission of the original owner of course). How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, as Apple doesn't provide this ability.

From [Apple's support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4895):

> You cannot merge two or more Apple IDs into a single one. You can, however, use one Apple ID for iCloud services and another Apple ID for store purchases (including iTunes in the Cloud and iTunes Match).

You can keep using all the old apps, but they won't update without the original password for the original Apple ID. In practice, you will eventually tire of the prompts or delete the apps in question. In the short term, you can use them all without needing the other account name or password.

Answer (score 0):

When you buy a used iPhone, just ask a previous owner to delete this phone from his devices at icloud.com > Find iPhone. If you don't restore this iPhone to factory settings all the apps will be kept on this device and you'll be able to use them. Enter your Apple ID details into iCloud and App Store, iTunes Store in Settings. You'll be able to download new apps using your Apple ID and keep apps downloaded by previous owner at the same time. The only thing you won't be able do is to update apps purchased by the other guy.